# Java EJB not injecting

Tags: java, ejb

My TestBean

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean implements TestLocal {
    public String getMessage(String name) {
        return "Test "+ name;
    }
}
```

My interface

```
@Local
public interface TestLocal {
    public String getMessage(String name);
}
```

Here I'm using it

```
@EJB
private TestLocal testLocal;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String result;=testLocal.getMessage("ASDASD");
    req.getSession().setAttribute("Test1",result);
    RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp");
    rd.forward(req,resp);
}
```

and I get NullPointerException on result row.

Comment: You should have the ejb and the servlet in the same EAR project. Otherwise, use the remote access.

Answer (score -2):

EJBs are only injected in managed beans. A bean is managed when it's managed by some injection container, such as via JSF's own @ManagedBean, CDI's @Named, etc. You can even inject an EJB in another EJB. You cannot inject an EJB in an unmanaged class. **I don't see your class as managed one by injection container**.

Comment: Thanks. How can i resolve this problem without other frameworks ?

Comment: Are you using any injection container.... ? If so, then have to use command as per that. Example: If you're using Spring as injection container, you can make class as managed one by adding @Component annoation on class level.

Comment: I dont use injection containers

Comment: [Plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do) is not appreciated. Please revise your answer to include the sources where you found the information instead of copypasting it verbatim and doing off as your own.